# Work-In-Progress Lexer

Tags: c++, lexical-analysis

So, purely out of desire to learn, I decided to take on a project of making my own very basic programming language from scratch. After which, I made a lexer.

I've tested the lexer (but only a bit) and it seems to work. But, I tend to doubt myself  a lot (which might actually be a good thing). So I I'd like people to review my code.

Just remember that I'm doing this in order to learn, so the code is most likely far from flawless, but I tried my best. Also, as I stated inside the code in comments, the error showing part is still work-in-progress so I've used placeholders instead, just ignore those for now. Ignore everything with the `show_error` function used.

Also I didn't provide source code for the `reader` class definition or declaration, but the `reader` class I used is quite basic so I don't think I would need to post it here, it should be possible to review the lexer without seeing the reader anyway.

Also, the language itself is very C-like for now... I gave the language the codename "Phi". But just treat it as if it were a C lexer for now.

So, here is the code of the lexer:

[declaration] lexer.hpp:

```cpp
// lexer.hpp
// Contains declaration of the Phi Lexer class

#ifndef PHI_LEXER
#define PHI_LEXER

#include "reader.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

class token
{
public:
    enum class kinds : char{kw, iden, op, symbol, int_lit, flt_lit, str_lit, null};
    // Enum class to represent every possible "kind" of token

    token();
    token(kinds kind, std::string token_val, std::size_t pos_line, std::size_t pos_col);

    std::string value() const;
    kinds kind() const;
    std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> pos() const;

    bool isNull() const;

    bool operator==(const token& other) const;
    bool operator!=(const token& other) const;

private:
    kinds knd; // Token kind
    std::string val;
    std::size_t line, col;
};

class tokenstream
{
public:
    token get();
    token peek(std::size_t step = 0) const;

    std::size_t size() const;

    void unget(std::size_t amount = 0);

    void push(token tok);
    void pop();

    void clear();

    bool contains(token tok) const;

    bool empty() const;

private:
    std::vector<token> tokens;
    std::size_t index;
};

namespace lexer_dict
{
    static const std::unordered_set<std::string> keywords {"If", "Else", "While", "For"};

    static const std::unordered_set<char> operators {'+', '-', '*', '/', '%',
                                                    '>', '<', '=', '!'};

    static const std::unordered_set<std::string> double_operators
    {">=", "<=", "!=", "+=", "-=", "*=", "/=", "%="};

    static const std::unordered_set<char> symbols {',', ';', ':', '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']'};

    static const std::unordered_set<char> whitespace {' ', '\n', '\t', '\v', '\r', '\f'};
} // Lexer dictionary to identify type of a character or string

class lexer
{
public:
    lexer();

    bool tokenize(reader read);

    const tokenstream &value() const;

private:
    tokenstream val; // The output value
};

#endif
```

[definition] lexer.cpp:

```cpp
// lexer.cpp
// Contains implementation of the Phi Lexer class
// WARNING: Errors are Work In Progress. Use it at your own risk

#include "lexer.hpp"
#include "errhandler.hpp"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>

using kinds = token::kinds;

token::token() : knd{token::kinds::null}, val{},line{}, col{}
{
}

token::token(kinds kind, std::string token_val, std::size_t pos_line, std::size_t pos_col)
: knd{kind}, val{token_val}, line{pos_line}, col{pos_col}
{
}

std::string token::value() const
{
    return val;
}

token::kinds token::kind() const
{
    return knd;
}

std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> token::pos() const
{
    return std::make_pair(line, col);
}

bool token::isNull() const
{
    return knd == token::kinds::null;
}

bool token::operator==(const token& other) const
{
    return knd == other.knd && val == other.val;
}

bool token::operator!=(const token& other) const
{
    return !(*this == other);
}

token tokenstream::get()
{
    if(tokens.size() > index)
        return tokens[index++];
    else
        throw std::out_of_range("Trying to read past token stream");
}

token tokenstream::peek(std::size_t step /*= 0*/) const
{
    if(tokens.size() > index + step)
        return tokens[index + step];
    else
        throw std::out_of_range("Trying to read past token stream");
}

std::size_t tokenstream::size() const
{
    return tokens.size() - index;
}

void tokenstream::unget(std::size_t amount /*= 1*/)
{
    if(static_cast<long long>(index - amount) >= 0)
        index -= amount;

    else
        throw std::out_of_range("Trying to read before token stream");
}

void tokenstream::push(token tok)
{
    tokens.push_back(tok);
}

void tokenstream::pop()
{
    tokens.pop_back();
}

void tokenstream::clear()
{
    index = 0;
    tokens.clear();
}

bool tokenstream::contains(token tok) const
{
    return std::find(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), tok) != tokens.end();
}

bool tokenstream::empty() const
{
    return tokens.size() - index <= 0;
}

lexer::lexer() : val{}
{
}

bool lexer::tokenize(reader read)
{
    auto is_oper = [](char c) -> bool
    {
        return lexer_dict::operators.find(c) != lexer_dict::operators.end();
    };

    auto is_double_oper = [](std::string &s) -> bool
    {
        return lexer_dict::double_operators.find(s) != lexer_dict::double_operators.end();
    };

    auto is_sym = [](char c) -> bool
    {
        return lexer_dict::symbols.find(c) != lexer_dict::symbols.end();
    };

    auto is_space = [](char c) -> bool
    {
        return lexer_dict::whitespace.find(c) != lexer_dict::whitespace.end();
    };

    auto is_kw = [](const std::string &s) -> bool
    {
        return lexer_dict::keywords.find(s) != lexer_dict::keywords.end();
    };

    // Lambda to check if character can be in a Numeric Literal

    std::size_t i{}, line{1}, col{1}, begin_col{};
    // i : index
    // line : current line
    // col : current column
    // begin_col : beginning column of the current token being processed

    const std::string& str = read.value();
    std::string temp_str;

    bool success = true;

    while(i < str.length())
    {
        if(is_space(str[i]))
        {
            if(str[i] == '\n' || str[i] == '\v')
            {
                col = 1;
                ++line;
                ++i;
            }

            else
            {
                ++col;
                ++i;
            }
        }

        else if(is_sym(str[i]))
        {
            val.push(token{kinds::symbol, str.substr(i, 1), line, col});
            ++col;
            ++i;
        }

        else if (is_oper(str[i]))
        {
            // If str[i] is the last character (which is invalid syntax but it's for the parser to deal with)
            // or if the next character isn't an operator,
            // then just insert it normally into the token stream
            if(i == str.length() - 1 || !is_oper(str[i+1]))
            {
                val.push(token{kinds::op, str.substr(i, 1), line, col});
                ++col;
                ++i;
            }

            // If str[i] is not the last character and the next character is also an operator,
            // which means it's a double operator (eg: <=, >=, !=),
            // ensure it's not an invalid operator combination (eg: not +- or *+)
            // and then push it in the token stream
            else
            {
                temp_str = str[i] + str[i + 1];

                if(is_double_oper(temp_str))
                    val.push(token{kinds::op, temp_str, line, col});

                else
                {
                    show_error("stuff"); // Not finished yet
                    success = false;
                    break;
                }

                col += 2;
                i += 2;
                temp_str.clear();
            }

        }

        else if (str[i] == '"')
        {
            std::size_t next_quote = str.find('"', i + 1);
            // Find the next quote from starting from the next position

            if(next_quote == std::string::npos)
            {
                // If no closing quote is found, show an error and set success flag to false
                show_error("stuff"); // Not finished yet
                success = false;
                break;
            }

            val.push(token(kinds::str_lit, str.substr(i + 1, next_quote - i - 1), line, col));
            // Make a substring containing everything inside the quotes, turn it into a token
            // And push it into the tokenstream

            col += next_quote - i + 1;
            i = next_quote + 1;
        }

        else if(isdigit(str[i]))
        {
            begin_col = col;
            // Store beginning column of token
            // Since a numeric literal can't span multiple lines,
            // We don't need to store the line

            bool allow_sign = false;
            bool expect_num = false;
            bool dot_found = false;
            bool e_found = false;

            // allow_sign : Flag to allow a plus or minus sign if 'e' is encountered while lexing a numeric literal
            // expect_num : Flag to check if the current char is '.' or 'e' so the next char must be a number
            // dot_found : Flag to determine if '.' has been encountered
            // e_found : Flag to determine if 'e' has been encountered

            while (!(is_space(str[i]) || is_sym(str[i])))
            {
                if(isdigit(str[i]))
                {
                    allow_sign = false;
                    expect_num = false;
                }

                else if(str[i] == '.')
                {
                    if(expect_num || dot_found || e_found)
                    {
                        show_error("stuff"); // Not finished yet
                        success = false;
                        temp_str.clear();
                        break;
                    }

                    dot_found = true;
                    expect_num = true;
                }

                else if(str[i] == 'e')
                {
                    if (expect_num || e_found)
                    {
                        show_error("stuff"); // Not finished yet
                        success = false;
                        temp_str.clear();
                        break;
                    }

                    allow_sign = true;
                    expect_num = true;
                    e_found = true;
                }

                else if(str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-')
                {
                    if (expect_num || !allow_sign)
                    {
                        show_error("stuff"); // Not finished yet
                        success = false;
                        temp_str.clear();
                        break;
                    }

                    allow_sign = false;
                    expect_num = false;
                }

                temp_str += str[i];

                ++col;
                ++i;
            }

            val.push(
                token((dot_found || e_found) ? kinds::flt_lit : kinds::int_lit,
                      temp_str, line, begin_col));

            temp_str.clear();
        }

        // Identifiers must start with an alphabet or an underscore '_'
        // All keywords start with an alphabet
        else if(isalpha(str[i]) || str[i] == '_')
        {
            begin_col = col;
            // Store beginning column of token
            // Since a keyword or identifier can't span multiple lines,
            // We don't need to store the line

            while (!(is_space(str[i]) || is_sym(str[i])))
            {
                temp_str += str[i];
                ++col;
                ++i;
            }

            if(is_kw(temp_str))
                val.push(token(kinds::kw, temp_str, line, begin_col));
            else
                val.push(token(kinds::iden, temp_str, line, begin_col));

            temp_str.clear();
        }

        // If a token begins with an invalid character, issue an error
        else
        {
            show_error("stuff"); // Not finished yet
            success = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return success;
}

const tokenstream &lexer::value() const
{
    return val;
}
```

I don't mind criticism. In fact, I would love advice on how to improve this. With that said, it'd be very helpful if you take your valuable time to review this.

Test case:
[source] [NOTE: The Program written in the language is completely random and has no purpose]

> ```
> Int i = 0;
>
> If(i < 0)
> {
>     i = 2 + 3.1;
>     testStr = "Test";
>     print("Test");
> }
>
> While(i >= 2)
> {
>     i--;
> }
> ```

Lexer output (using a print lexer function which prints the content stored in the lexer):

> ```
> Lexer:
> Token: KW, Val: "Int", Pos: (1, 1)
> Token: Iden, Val: "i", Pos: (1, 5)
> Token: Op, Val: "=", Pos: (1, 7)
> Token: IntLit, Val: "0", Pos: (1, 9)
> Token: Sym, Val: ";", Pos: (1, 10)
> Token: KW, Val: "If", Pos: (3, 1)
> Token: Sym, Val: "(", Pos: (3, 3)
> Token: Iden, Val: "i", Pos: (3, 4)
> Token: Op, Val: "<", Pos: (3, 6)
> Token: IntLit, Val: "0", Pos: (3, 8)
> Token: Sym, Val: ")", Pos: (3, 9)
> Token: Sym, Val: "{", Pos: (4, 1)
> Token: Iden, Val: "i", Pos: (5, 5)
> Token: Op, Val: "=", Pos: (5, 7)
> Token: IntLit, Val: "2", Pos: (5, 9)
> Token: Op, Val: "+", Pos: (5, 11)
> Token: FltLit, Val: "3.1", Pos: (5, 13)
> Token: Sym, Val: ";", Pos: (5, 16)
> Token: Iden, Val: "testStr", Pos: (6, 5)
> Token: Op, Val: "=", Pos: (6, 13)
> Token: StrLit, Val: "Test", Pos: (6, 15)
> Token: Sym, Val: ";", Pos: (6, 21)
> Token: Iden, Val: "print", Pos: (7, 5)
> Token: Sym, Val: "(", Pos: (7, 10)
> Token: StrLit, Val: "Test", Pos: (7, 11)
> Token: Sym, Val: ")", Pos: (7, 17)
> Token: Sym, Val: ";", Pos: (7, 18)
> Token: Sym, Val: "}", Pos: (8, 1)
> Token: KW, Val: "While", Pos: (10, 1)
> Token: Sym, Val: "(", Pos: (10, 6)
> Token: Iden, Val: "i", Pos: (10, 7)
> Token: Op, Val: ">=", Pos: (10, 9)
> Token: IntLit, Val: "2", Pos: (10, 12)
> Token: Sym, Val: ")", Pos: (10, 13)
> Token: Sym, Val: "{", Pos: (11, 1)
> Token: Iden, Val: "i", Pos: (12, 5)
> Token: Op, Val: "--", Pos: (12, 6)
> Token: Sym, Val: ";", Pos: (12, 8)
> Token: Sym, Val: "}", Pos: (13, 1)
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Since this is a lexer for your own programming language, it might help to post an example in that language just so that the reviewers can get a feeling what kind of syntax the code has to parse. From a quick look at your code, it seems to be C-like?

Comment: @AlexV Yes it is C-like. I thought it would be obvious enough so I didn't specifically mention it

Comment: Can you list the supported language constructs so far?

Comment: @L.F. I guess for now I'll stick to simple mathematic operations, simple things like If Statements and While Loops. That's all, for now

Comment: OK.  Can you provide some test cases to provide more context regarding how this is supposed to work?

Comment: @L.F. I added an example

Comment: @L.F. Also I fixed the lexer output, it seems the old output was from a previous version of the lexer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review!

## lexer.hpp

It is common practice to put standard headers before custom headers and sort them in alphabetical order:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include "reader.hpp"
```

Usually, class names are capitalized.

In general, try to avoid abbreviations.  The token kinds are more readable in full name:

```
enum class kinds {
    keyword,
    identifier,
    operator,
    symbol,
    int_literal,
    float_literal,
    string_literal,
    null,
};
```

(The last comma is intentional.)

Strings should be passed around by value.  Also, storing numbers as string probably isn't a very good idea.

Make a dedicated class for line-column number pairs.

`std::unordered_set` generally performs worse than `std::set` without a carefully crafted hash function.  Use `std::set`.

Currently, you are maintaining the class variant yourself.  Things will become much easier if you use `std::variant`.

## lexer.cpp

Instead of defining the default constructor yourself, use in-class member initializers and `= default` the default constructor.  The other constructor should move from `token_val`, not copy.

`pos` can just return `{line, col}`.  (Also see above for making a dedicated position class.)

The lambdas don't need to explicitly specify `-> bool`.  `is_double_oper` should accept by `const` reference.

Consistently put a space after a control keyword like `while`.

The `tokenize` function is becoming very very long.  It should be cut down into several functions.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll try to do all the stuff you suggested. I don't get one thing though, what exactly do you mean by "class variant"? I don't see anything related to variants in my code..

Comment: @Arnil Basically, I mean the way you interpret the value (which is represented by a `std::string`) depends on the kind field.

Comment: How can I use std::variant for it? I mean, the kinds are not separate types but just what kind of token the string represents

Comment: @Arnil Define a tag type for each token kind.  For null, there is no data (`struct Null {};`).  For integer literals, for example, you can store them as an `int` rather than a string (`struct Int_literal { int value; };`).  Similarly for the rest.  (Also, don't accept so fast, give others some time.)

Comment: Also any advice on how I can shorten the tokenize function? Like, what will I make smaller functions for?

Comment: Also why would that [defining tag types for tokens and using variant] be a better idea than doing what I am doing right now?

Comment: @Arnil The first thing that comes to mind is to extract the branches of the long `if else if` chain.

Comment: @Arnil Because the semantics is clearer, especially when you add more complex features later (think of user defined objects).

Comment: Alright I'll keep that in mind, thanks a lot for your advice, I really appreciate it.